# Using a numpy array as feature in Decision Tree Regressors

Tags: numpy, machine-learning, decision-tree

I am trying to implement a decision tree regressor algorithm on a pandas dataframe. One of the features is a numpy array. Here is a mock example:

```
data2 = {
'name':['firstium','secondium'],
'vec': [np.array([2, 3, 4, 0, 0, 0]),np.array([2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 3])],
'hardness':[2.5,2.4],
'refractive index':[1.9,1.0]
}

frame2=pd.DataFrame(data2,columns=['name','vec','hardness','refractive index'])


     name       vec                hardness refractive index
0   firstium    [2, 3, 4, 0, 0, 0]      2.5       1.9
1   secondium   [2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 3]      2.4       1.0
```

When I implement a DecisionTreeRegressor:

```
 from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeRegressor
 tree_reg=DecisionTreeRegressor()
 tree_reg.fit(frame2['vec'],frame2['hardness'])
```

I get the following error message:

```
 ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

I could convert this array into a column of individual values but some information will be lost in this process. Is there a way in which I can feed the whole array as one feature?

Thanks!

Comment: `DecisionTreeRegressor` is not in `sklearn.linear_model`, So the first line of your code should throw an error!

Comment: Also I gotta say that `Vec` is actually a list the way you have mentioned it, not a numpy array.